Docker randomly fails at removing containers during CI/CD pipeline on windows server
I have a Bamboo Server pipeline that uses containers to build the code and run automated tests. Both Bamboo and Docker run on a Windows Server 2019 machine. Everything ran smoothly for a couple years until a few days ago when, without any change to the configuration, Docker started failing removing containers. The failures are not consistent, most of the time it fails, less frequently it doesn't.
The error message I get is always the same ({CONTAINER_ID} is a placeholder for the actual container id):
Error waiting for container: container {CONTAINER_ID}: driver \"windowsfilter\" failed to remove root filesystem: failed to detach VHD: The device is not ready.: rename E:\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\{CONTAINER_ID} E:\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\{CONTAINER_ID}-removing: Access is denied.

After I get the error, launching docker container ls -a shows the container in the Removal in progress status. Removing the container from there with docker container rm CONTAINER_ID goes smoothly.
The containers are launched with -rm parameter.
I already tried to:

Restart the machine
Restart the docker service
Update Windows
Pruning all containers
Pruning all images
Pruning all volumes
Rebuilding the images
Running containers with process isolation (parameter --isolation=process, when launching docker contaienr run [...]
Watch for open handlers on the folder docker is trying to rename to check for concurrency issues (no one is accessing the folder)

I still haven't tried to disable the antivirus (organization policies).

sistematic (sic, misspelled) is likely not the word you want.  You either meant systemic, meaning that the failure affects the whole system, or possibly consistent, meaning that the failure is reproducible every time.  Regardless, you should try to provide a [mre].

You're right, thank you. It's a false friend in my language, fixed it. I cannot give any reproducible example unfortunately.

If your problem is not reproducible, then is it solved?  How are you reproducing it?

I am able to reproduce the error by re-launching the build, but I can't give out the container image or any code because of my organization policies. I can tell you that on windows desktop the container is correctly removed.

But you can create a example that is representative of the problem you are having.  Otherwise we'll have this conversation: "The problem occurs when I docker run foo. Others then respond "But I'm able to docker run foo without problems" and you'll respond, "well, I have to also do X..." and others will say "if I do X it still works", and then you'll say "Well, I have to do Y first as well, and I'm running on a system with property Z..." So just save everyone the back and forth trouble and fully describe what is required to elicit the problem from scratch to the best of your ability.
